# Ubuntu not showing up on boot menu after Wubi installation

Tags: boot, wubi, installation

I have installed Ubuntu to my hard drive using Wubi. The installation seemed to be successful; however, after rebooting my PC I am not brought to a boot menu, and Windows just starts normally. When I manually force my computer to a boot menu, Ubuntu is not listed.

Comment: Which version of Windows were you installing in?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP

Answer (score 4):

For XP, right click `My Computer`, click on `Properties`, click the `Advanced` tab, `Startup & Recovery` settings.

Make sure that the `Time to display operating systems` is 10.

If the timeout is not zero, then in rare cases there is a line missing from the end of the C:\boot.ini required to boot Ubuntu:
`C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"`

If you decide to edit the boot.ini, make sure you back it up, and edit it from the same place.

It should look something like this:

```
[boot loader] 
timeout=10 
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS 
[operating systems] 
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect 
C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"
```

For Windows 7, right click on `Computer`, `Properties`, `Advanced system settings` (on the left):

[image]

Then click on `Startup & Recovery` settings:

[image]

Make sure the `Time to display list of operations systems` is set to 10 or above. If that's not the problem, run `CMD.EXE` selecting to `Run as an administrator`, then enter `bcdedit` to make sure there is an entry for Ubuntu.