# Boot menu has a problem I can not boot Ubuntu or anything because the menu does not show

Tags: boot, wubi, windows-xp, mbr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu not showing up on boot menu after Wubi installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75314/ubuntu-not-showing-up-on-boot-menu-after-wubi-installation)

Alright so I downloaded and installed Ubuntu to a Windows XP machine via wubi. When I rebooted the boot menu didn't show up.