# Wubi: Hide Windows boot manager unless I want to boot Ubuntu

Tags: wubi, bootloader

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu through Wubi for learning and testing purposes. After that, every time I start the PC the Windows boot manager shows up and asks me which OS I want to boot into - *Ubuntu* or *Windows 7*.

Since most of the time I'm using Windows, I'd like to know if there's a way to skip the boot menu when turning on the PC and boot straight to Windows by default but still be able to press a key and boot to Ubuntu if I want to on the next restart.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Windows boot manager *Time to display operating systems* (timeout) to zero, making sure that Windows is still the default boot option, then the Windows boot manager will not be shown and it will boot directly to Windows. See [here for details](https://askubuntu.com/a/75326/14916) I don't believe there is any key you can press that will make the Windows boot manager show, but <kbd>F8</kbd> is supposed to give you alternative boot options. So try that first.

Otherwise, you can set a one-time boot into Ubuntu at the next reboot by going to a command prompt (run `CMD.EXE` by right-clicking and select *Run as Administrator*) and then determining the GUID for the Ubuntu entry and setting it to boot once. e.g. ([reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700231.aspx))

```
bcdedit /bootsequence {GUID}
```

Once you've got the GUID you could create a batch job (`.bat` file) to do this from the Desktop to make it more convenient.

To identify the GUID, run `bcdedit` and look for the Ubuntu entry e.g.:

```
Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu
```

The above shows the GUID as `1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029` so you would run:

```
bcdedit /bootsequence {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
```

So you could then create a `.bat` file with the above line in it, and right-click on it and *Run as administrator* to set it to boot to Ubuntu at the next start.

This isn't a convenient solution, but it should do the trick.