# Kubuntu 13.04 got installed inside Win7, but doesn't appear in boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, kubuntu, wubi

I've never used Ubuntu in parallel to Windows OS. I always installed Ubuntu inside Windows, with a dedicated drive for Ubuntu.

I did the same thing recently on my new Lenovo laptop. I created a separate drive of 50GB solely for Ubuntu.

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 ISO file and extracted. I copied the extracted folder in the dedicated drive. Using the Wubi installer in the folder, I chose Kubuntu from the dropdown menu of desktops.It downloaded full Kubuntu 13.04 and installed.

It also shows up in Windows **Control Panel > Programs and Features**.

But I cannot see anything in Boot Menu. It is as if there is no other OS at all.

After such a huge download of the entire Kubuntu 13.04, I do not want to simply uninstall  for a clean drive again.

Please help if there is a way to boot into this newly installed Kubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

The Kubuntu ISO is sitting in `x:\ubuntu\install\` (replace *x* with the drive you installed on). It has been renamed to `installation.iso`. Move that out of the `\ubuntu\` directory (right out or it gets deleted when you uninstall).

Once you have the ISO you can write it to a USB stick.

Second, since this is a new Lenovo I am going to assume that it has Windows 8 and boots via  UEFI. If this is not the case, let me know, but even if you do get Wubi booting, it will fail as it cannot work on GPT formatted drives (always come with UEFI and Windows). Refer to this for instructions: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

So I would use that USB stick to install and not bother with Wubi. If on the other hand you have an older BIOS based machine, you can see this to fix your current issue: [Ubuntu not showing up on boot menu after Wubi installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75314/ubuntu-not-showing-up-on-boot-menu-after-wubi-installation)