# windows xp dual-boot (wubi install) stopped working for ubuntu - gives "missing or corrupt system32\hal.dll" error

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-xp

This was working fine for a year or three - something happened in the last month or so.

I'm pretty sure that the missing hal.dll file isn't the actual problem - the file is there, and windows works fine. (I found out the hard way that windows doesn't work without it(!?!), but that's another story.)

I've looked at the boot.ini file, but I don't see anything obvious (to me) wrong with it. It looks almost identical to the example in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75314/ubuntu-not-showing-up-on-boot-menu-after-wubi-installation). I'll try to post mine later today.

I can't think what might have changed. I vaguely recall an ubuntu update the last time I was using it - could that be an issue?

Comment: Make sure that `wubildr.mbr` exists in the path listed in the `boot.ini` file. I believe this can also be caused by invalid edits to the `boot.ini` (invalid line endings if you edit in linux)

Comment: That was it! The 2 wubildr files were missing from c:\ (?) - copied wubildr.mbr over and got a "cannot find GRLDR" error. Looked that up and copied wubildr as well, and presto! Thanks, bcbc!

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise I could (or was supposed to) answer my own question. I'm new here. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 wubildr files were missing from c:\ (?) - copied wubildr.mbr over and got a "cannot find GRLDR" error. Looked that up and copied wubildr as well (both from C:\ubuntu\winboot), and presto!

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any "fixmbr" or "bootcfg -whatever"? Did you install another Windows system?

Always remember that doing any of that leaves the ubuntu install unusable (unless you happen to have the live-cd, in which you can install GRUB -not for Wubi's like in your case).

If you didn't do any of that, try to think about anything weird that could have happened to the computer before that.

Comment: I didn't change anything I can remember. All I can think of are a few updates (Windows _and_ ubuntu, possibly), maybe a power out or two....?    If I need to reinstall, will I be able to recover files from ubuntu somehow?